# DP solution to find if there is group of numbers which is divisible by M

Tags: algorithm

Let's say we have number N, such that 0 < N <= 10^6 and 2 <= M <= 10^3 and array of N elements a[1], a[2], ... a[N] (0<= a[i] <=10^9)\

Now we have to check if we can choose group of numbers from the array such that their sum will be divisible by M, and output "YES" or "NO".

Here are two examples:

N = 3, M =5 a={1,2,3} answer="YES"

N = 4, M = 6 a={3,1,1,3} answer="YES"

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be a specific programming question, but a pure math question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I disagree. DP is computer specific and thus acceptable.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I have no clue what DP is, but the question itself only deals in math concepts, and doesn't show any attempt at solving this itself. Even if I'm wrong with my classification, it deserves to be closed being too broad.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel although the formatting is poor, the problem is clearly explained (and it's a programming contest question). I agree with that the OP is copy pasting his homework and not showing his attempt at solving.

Answer (score 2):

C++ solution.

```
//declare dp array of boolean values of size M
bool dp[M] = {0}; // init with fasle values
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    bool ndp[M] = {0}; // init temporary boolean array
    ndp[a[i] % M] = 1; // add a subset with one a[i] element
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) 
        if(dp[j]) { // if we may find a subset of elements with sum = j (modulo M)
            ndp[j] = 1; // copy existing values
            ndp[(j + a[i]) % M] = 1; // extend the subset with a[i], which will give a sum = j + a[i] (modulo M)
        }
    // copy from ndp to dp before proceeding to the next element of a
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) dp[j] = ndp[j];
}

//check dp[0] for the answer
```

The algorithm complexity will be **O(N*M)** which in your case is **O(10<sup>9</sup>)**

**Edit:** Added `ndp[a[i] % M] = 1;` line in order to make dp[j] ever become nonzero.

---

There might be another alternative **O(M * M * log(M) + N)** solution which in your case is **O(10<sup>7</sup>)** (but with big constant).

Notice that if substitute each `a[i]` with `a[i] % M` the problem statement does not change. Lets count the number of `a[i]` elements that give specific remainder `j` after division on `M`. If for some remainder `j` we found `k` elements in `a` then we can generate the following sums of subsets (that may produce unique remainder)

`j,  2 * j % M,  3 * j % M  ...  k * j % M`

Example: let `M = 6` and for remainder `2` we found `5` elements in `a`. Then we have the following unique sums of subsets:

`2 % 6,  2 * 2 % 6,  3 * 2 % 6,  4 * 2 % 6,  5 * 2 % 6`
which is `0, 2, 4` 
store this information in boolean form `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}`

At most we have `M` such groups that produce `M`-size bool array of possible remainders.

Next we need to find all possible subsets that may appear if we will take elements of different groups. Lets say we merge two bool remainder arrays `a` and `b` if we can introduce new array `c` that will contain all possible remainder sums of elements from subset of `a` and `b`. Naive approach will require us to make two nested loops over `a` and `b` giving **O(M<sup>2</sup>)** merge time complexity.

We may reduce complexity to **O(M * log(M))** using **Fast Fourier Transform** algo.  Each bool array has a polynomial **Σ a<sub>i</sub>*x<sup>i</sup>** where coefficients **a<sub>i</sub>** are taken from bool array. If we want to merge two array we may just multiply their polynomials.

Overall complxity is **O(M<sup>2</sup> * log(M))** as we need to make `M` such merges.

Comment: I think you also need to add "ndp[a[i]%M]=1;" into the inner loop because otherwise it is impossible for dp[j] to ever become nonzero.